# Java Database Driven Business Rules - Design Thoughts?

Tags: java, spring, ejb, scalability, rules

My enterprise application is currently Running on Weblogic 10.3.4, Java 1.6 and Spring 2.0.8. It's a recent upgrade hence Spring is yet to be updated and some of the java code base is still in old 1.4 style.

At the moment we use a propriatory rules engine to run our business rules. However, this is overkill as we use none of the inference engine functionality and we can no longer justify the license costs. The plan is to write a database driven rules engine.

Each form request will have any number of rules associated with it, which wiull be configured using a few basic database tables.

My design so far is that each rule defined in the database will map via Spring to a Singleton Stateless Spring bean. Given a form state each rule will return a Result respose object. See code snippet below:

```
 //get List of rules for form from database
 List<RuleConfiguration>  rules = RulesService.getRulesForFormRuleset(formType, filingMethod, rsName, document);

    IssueDocument issues = new IssueDocumentImpl();

     for (RuleConfiguration ruleConfig : rules) {


         //create a rule instance from the Spring Bean Factory
         Rule rule = (Rule) beanFactory.getBean(ruleConfig.getRule().getRuleBeanName());
         RulesIssue issue = rule.runRule(document, ruleConfig);

            if (issue != null)  {  //Issue has been populated rule must have fired
                issues.addNewIssue(issue);
            }
     }

    return issues;
```

Does this sound like a sensible solution? I was keen to implement a "light-touch" solution so steered clear of EJB as there are over 500 rules that will eventually have to be written. My main concern is that as these are all singletons and there will be a heavy demand on my "rules engine" do I need to consider some sort of bean pooling? Any other feedback would be most welcome. Rip me to shreds if you like - I can take it!

Many Thanks

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel instead of using the open source rules engine?

Comment: just so you know, "proprietary" generally means "a custom system we own and made ourselves"

Comment: Maybe they don't want to introduce several megs of unknown, potentially (likely) underdocumented black box logic in to their infrastructure when perhaps all they need is a list of class names with some metadata filtering on it that they can iterate over.

Comment: @Will Hartung - the question clearly states *there are over 500 rules that will eventually have to be written*

Comment: @matt b - So? The complexity of a rule system isn't in the number of the rules, it's derivation and relationships of them at any particular point. You can go a long way with attaching simple meta data to little bits of logic that found using a simple DB query, and then bluntly executed. Consider the AOP aspects of something like EJB session beans. AroundInvoke methods. That's it. Configured through annotation at compile time, or XML at run time. That's all there is. That's a simple rule system with simple meta data. No big deal. Even if you have 500 of them.

Comment: I'm will Will on this. Although the number of rules to execute is potentially large they are all pretty simple and return a simple pass/fail that is wrapped up and passed back to the client. I condsidered using several open source rules engines and found all of them over engineered for my purposes. I also wanted the rules to be POJOs that would be easily maintainable by junior support staff without having to learn a new rules DSL.

Comment: Also Matt without being pedantic just so you know "proprietary" means "manufactured and sold only by the owner of the patent, formula, brand name, or trademark associated with the product" like the current Rules Engine I use ;-) See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proprietary_software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly there are two gross areas of work to do in this kind of thing.

The first is to identify the rules to fire, and the second is to actually execute them.

Depending on your filtering and the dynamism, the rule queries can likely be readily memoized, so likely the cost of the lookup will approach zero. 500 rules isn't really a lot, when you think about it.

Next, is actual execution. If all of your things are singletons, then you'll need to be concerned about singleton startup, thread safety, etc.

Basically, just make sure each of your rules has a lifecycle. "start" "run" "stop". If it's a true singleton that needs some state from run to run, then the start and stop methods will likely have logic in them. If it's just a bit of logic to run on the inputs, then there's probably no need to have start and stop (they can be empty methods), or for it to be a singleton at all, so just make a new instance, fire it, and throw it away.

You don't mention what a "rule" is in terms of logic. They can easily be simple Java classes that follow this lifecycle. Add a @SingeletonRule annotation, or implement isSingleton, whatever.

Really, at this level there's little rocket science to this kind of system. The magic is mostly in the meta data and the actual creating of the list of rules for execution.

Simple rule systems are simple.

Comment: Thanks Will. Really usesful, the idea is to keep it as simple as possible. Really liking the annotation idea to get around the lifecycle issue. Thanks again